# How many bits can be transfered through Ethernet at each time?

Tags: tcp, bandwidth, ethernet

I am writing a networking application. It has some unxpected lags. I need to calculate some figures but I cant find an information - how many bits can be transferes through Ethernet connection at each tick.

I know that the resulting transfer rate is 100Mbps/1Gbps. But ethernet should use hardware ticks to sync both ends I suppose. So it moves data in ticks.

So the question is how many ticks per second or how many bits per one tick used in ethernet.

The actual connection is 100 Mbps full-duplex.

Comment: It's more likely to be a problem of latency rather than throughput. You need to know how big your packets are and how much latency there is in your TCP/IP stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Here is the article: http://discountcablesusa.com/ethernetcables.html

The first table says 100BaseTX has frequency 31.25MHz, the signal rate is 125Mb (25 is Ehternet overhead so we receive 100Mbit/s of "useful" data).

Hence 125/31.25 = **4bit per one transmition** which is roughly the answer on my question.